# How to reset number to 0 after running program once again

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

I'm making program which converts sum of the numbers entered by user to binary, octal and hexadecimal. I would like to give a user an option to run program once again but with different numbers. Here is the problem - each time user repeats numbers, sum of these numbers are added to the previous entry. How do I stop incrementing? Is there any way to reset sum to 0? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: `sum = 0;` in the beginning of the first while-loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to reset sum to 0?

Yes, set `sum` to 0 right before the inner loop.

```
sum = 0;
while(1)
{
    printf("Enter number: ");
    scanf("%d", &value);
    sum += value;
    if(value == 0)break;
}
```

Also, rather then using `while (1)` with a `break` condition at the end, use a `do..while` loop.

```
sum = 0;
do {
    printf("Enter number: ");
    scanf("%d", &value);
    sum += value;
} while (value != 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You would simply need to **reset your sum variable to 0** if the user wants to reuse the number system with other numbers -

```
printf("\nEnter numbers once again? (y/n)\n");
scanf(" %c", &j);
printf("\n\nENTERING ONCE AGAIN\n");

if(j == 'n'||j == 'N')break;
***else sum = 0***
```